# How can i stream parquet file over network using client server socket programming in java

Tags: java, sockets, parquet, serversocket, parquet-mr

i am using `ParquetReader<Group> reader = new ParquetReader<Group>(path, groupReadSupport);` for reading parquet file from local.

i want to know how can i stream parquet file line by line over network

i want know how can i pass that row data through client socket line by line but i don't want to pass string format i want to pass in parquet format in server socket and from server socket i want to process that in and print that in string format

Comment: So the question is "how do I read row data from the reader?", or "how do I use Sockets?", or both?

Comment: hi @thanopi57  i want know how can i pass that row data through client socket line by line  but i don't want to pass string format i want to pass in parquet format  in server socket and from server socket i want to process that in and  print that in string format.

Answer (score 1):

`ParquetReader` internally uses an [`InputFile`](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/apache-parquet-1.10.1/parquet-common/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/io/InputFile.java) abstraction for reading from different sources. The default implementation is `HadoopInputFile`, which uses one of the file systems implementations supported by hadoop. You could try implementing your own `InputFile` and [create the reader from that](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/apache-parquet-1.10.1/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/hadoop/ParquetReader.java#L167), but I don't think this would be possible for a purely streaming input.

A parquet file contains metadata about the contained columns, their types and statistics, which is needed for processing the data. This metadata is contained at the end of the file, which makes writing files in a streaming manner possible. But reading requires the possibility to seek to the end of the file, read the length of this metadata, then seek to the beginning of the metadata to read that, and finally seeking to the beginning of the actual column data.